# (React-firebase-hooks) How to query firebase documents in descending order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I believe the firebase cloud firestore queries documents in ascending order. I've seen some of the solutions online which suggests to initiate the values as negatives, but it is a timestamp object and corresponds to the data fields in firebase, so storing it as a negative certainly won't work, right? Of course, I can have another field that's ordered and use that as the .orderBy argument, but it would be best to avoid that.

This app I've building is a chat app, hence the need to query the messages in descending order of timeStamps. Here is how I'm currently retrieve the data.

```js
    const messagesRef = firebase.firestore().collection(props.chatNum);
    const query = messagesRef.orderBy('timeSent').limit(10);
    const [messages] = useCollectionData(query, { idField : 'id' });

    return (
        <div className="messageBox">
            {messages && messages.map(message => (
                <Message key={message.id} text={message.text} spent={message.timeSent}/>
            ))}
        </div>

    )
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google Firebase has this almost secret resource called "documentation" that you can use to learn about it's various options, such as:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#orderby

```
orderBy
orderBy ( fieldPath :  string | FieldPath ,  directionStr ? :  OrderByDirection ) : Query < T >
Creates and returns a new Query that's additionally sorted by the specified field, optionally in descending order instead of ascending.

Parameters
fieldPath: string | FieldPath
The field to sort by.

Optional directionStr: OrderByDirection
Optional direction to sort by (asc or desc). If not specified, order will be ascending.

Returns Query<T>
The created Query.
```

Comment: LMAO, I'm sorry, I literally looked everywhere for this, but just wasn't able to find it. All these posts are referring to insert with a different value. Thanks for this!